# How to save a dictionary with key having value of type object

Tags: django, python-3.x, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to save an object in mongodb using pymongo. I am calling an api which gives me and object and by iterating through object i am able to get fields and values. But problem is there may be some fields whose value is also an object and when i tried to store such fileds in mongodb i am getting errors.

Error is **document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping**

**models.py**

```
class UnusedResources(Document):
    field1 = fields.StringField(max_length=20)
    field2 = fields.DictField()
```

**python shell**

```
object = API   #calling api
d = dict()

d['field1'] = None
d['field2'] = object.__dict__  #converted all fields of object into dict and stored in d['field2']

client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
db = client.CESdatabase
collection = db.registration_unusedresources
collection.insert_one(d)
```

**fields inside object**

```
{
 'additional_properties': {}, 
 'id': '/subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/auth-user-api/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/XXX', 
 'name': 'XXX',  
 'sku': <azure.mgmt.network.v2018_11_01.models.load_balancer_sku_py3.LoadBalancerSku object at 0x0000000004E05D30>,
 'probes': [<azure.mgmt.network.v2018_11_01.models.probe_py3.Probe object at 0x0000000004E05DA0>], 
 'inbound_nat_rules': [], 
 'inbound_nat_pools': [], 
 'outbound_rules': None
}
```

Comment: what is the type of the variable 'object' ? can you post an example of the response from the API ?

Comment: what is the purpuse of doing `d = dict()` and `d['field2'] = d`? Are u recursively assigning a dict to its key? It is a valid Python expression, but it might be not supported by your database.

Comment: @Chiefir sorry that was my mistake, i was trying store all fields inside of an object to `d['filed2']`.

Comment: So that is what I actually said?

Comment: @VamsiKrishnaB api returns an object and by doing this `object.__dict__`  i am getting all fields inside of an object like

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance of `azure.mgmt.network.v2018_11_01.models.load_balancer_sku_py3.LoadBalancerSku` and `azure.mgmt.network.v2018_11_01.models.probe_py3.Probe` in your API response. This is something that Mongo cannot store (rightly so). You need to determine how you want to serialize those as well.